# How to manually validate data in struts 2

Tags: validation, struts2

where and how to implement the `validate(){}` method for validating the data on the form, in struts 2, please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, the validate method is delcared in the ActionSupport class and we should override it in our Action class (First we should extend the ActionSupport Class) as follows,

```
public class Login extends ActionSupport {
//execute method goes here 
//getter/setters goes here
@Override
public void validate() {
super.validate();
    System.out.println("User Name " + getUserName());
    if(getUserName().length()==0)
         addFieldError("userName", "User Name Required");

    }

}
```

and also you should define your action in strus.xml as follows

```
<action name="DemoLogin" class="com.demo.Login">
    <result name="SUCCESS">/LoginSuccess.jsp</result>
    <result name="ERROR">/LoginError.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/Login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

here `<result name="input">/Login.jsp</result>` this tag is imp bcoz, if dont add this tag the filter dispathcer, wont come to know which page to render if validation-error occur.